# Can I use type abbreviation as an alias inside a generic class?

Tags: f#

I am making an object pool class with custom pointer sizes. It gets tedious to type names and generic parameters all the time. Could I do something like this:

```
type ObjectPool<'P, 'T when 'T: unmanaged>(size: int) =
  type PTR = TypedPointer<'P, 'T>

  ... use PTR instead of TypedPointer<'P, 'T> here ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can declare a type alias inside a class, similar to how you cannot declare nested classes.  Therefore, the closest you could get would be to declare a private type alias inside the module/namespace, but you would still have to preserve the type parameters:

```
module Pool

type private Ptr<'p,'t> = TypedPointer<'p,'t>

type ObjectPool<'p,'t>() =
    let pointers: Ptr<'p,'t> list = []
```

Comment: But then I still have to provide generic types all the time.